# Why does a SQLite database created in Python have the VARCHAR data type?

Tags: python, sqlite

When I create an SQLite database from a python data model, any column defined as a String in Python is displayed as VARCHAR in SQLite (viewing with DB Browser for SQLite). Here is an example of the data model in Python:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(10))
    name_first = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    name_last = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

This may not be relevant, but I should clarify that I'm doing this as part of a website hosted with Flask. The database is initially created by dropping to a python prompt and:

```
from app import db
db.create_all()
```

I have a basic understanding of MS SQL and SQLite datatypes (NULL,INTEGER,REAL,TEXT,BLOB), but I don't understand why I'm seeing the columns defined as Strings in Python classified as VARCHAR in DB Browser for SQLite. If I attempt to modify the table, I see all of the expected datatypes for SQLite and also VARCHAR as an option. If I create a new database/table, then VARCHAR doesn't exist as an option for datatypes. Why wouldn't these columns be displayed as TEXT datatypes?

Comment: Use `db.Text()` instead of `db.String(size)` if you want a TEXT column?

Answer (score 1):

> Strings in Python classified as VARCHAR in DB Browser for SQLite.

In Flask you are actually using `SQLAlchemy` ORM which will convert your class models directly into SQLite statements to create the relational database tables corresponding to it.

`String` data type in Python class model will be as `VARCHAR` data type in SQLite using Object Relational Mapper.

In SQLite, `Text` is the parent of `VARCHAR` and in the default installation is no different, so `VARCHAR` is actually same as `TEXT`.

Also If you check **3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity** in the documentation you notice in the second point that:

> If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
> "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
> type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
> affinity.

For more info check : http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

[image]

Comment: I understand that TEXT and VARCHAR are the same. I do not understand why DB Browser for SQLite shows the type as VARCHAR and why both TEXT and VARCHAR are options in the dropdown (if I Modify the table in the GUI). If I create a table in this GUI, I only have the TEXT option.

Comment: If you check 3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity in the documentation you notice in the second point that: "If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity."

Comment: So there is no real issue in showing `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`. they are both assigned to text affinity in SQLite.

Comment: If you find my answer useful mark it as accepted. wish your issue solved.